# How to use gcloud preview app run without boot2docker?

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, docker, boot2docker, gcloud

I'm trying to run a Dart app on my machine, to be eventually deployed on Google App Engine. I've followed the instructions found on this page

https://www.dartlang.org/cloud/

The difference is I already have a local docker daemon running, which I'd like to use, and don't really want to use VirtualBox.  The instructions assume you are using boot2docker, which insists on using VirtualBox to install an VirtualBox VM and run the docker daemon on this.  Everytime I try and run

```
gcloud preview app run app.yaml
```

I get

```
google.appengine.tools.docker.containers.DockerDaemonConnectionError: 
Couldn't connect to the docker daemon because the required environment 
variables were not set. Please check the environment variables 
DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_CERT_PATH and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY are set correctly. 
If you are using boot2docker, make sure you have run "$(boot2docker shellinit)
```

I sense from what I've read, that you don't have to use boot2docker, and use a local docker daemon instance.  The problem is I can't find any instructions on how to do this.  I am hoping someone can answer this for me.  Also the error message I am given doesn't help me, as any google search I do keeps giving me the same answer of use, boot2docker.

Comment: Gunter could you provide a link to this duplicate question please?

Comment: I see you've already done it, thanks

Comment: I see no accepted answer on the linked question. There is no indication via the comments which answer is the correct one for this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed Docker 1.3.2 from `unstable` (Debian), added

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-d -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://localhost:2375"
```

to `/etc/default/docker`, and set

```
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375
```

to make it work.

This page http://docs.docker.com/articles/https/ contains more information about how to configure docker for HTTPS.

I created an issue https://github.com/dart-lang/www.dartlang.org/issues/1162 to update the setup instructions for Dart.

Comment: Though I'm running docker through systemd, but this pretty much answers my question, even if the answer is also found in another duplicate question

Comment: I just found this, as I faced the same issue, and edited the mentioned file by adding the 2 lines above, still getting this error:
'Couldn\'t connect to the docker daemon using the specified '
google.appengine.tools.docker.containers.DockerDaemonConnectionError: Couldn't connect to the docker daemon using the specified environment variables. Please check the environment variables DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_CERT_PATH and DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY are set correctly. If you are using boot2docker, make sure you have run "$(boot2docker shellinit)"

Comment: Restart Docker `sudo /etc/init.d/docker restart` after the change and check with `echo $DOCKER_HOST` if the setting of the variable is active.